# Is o365 upgraded from SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint 2016?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

Is SharePoint o365 continues deployment platform (fix bugs and introduce new features at frequent internal). I can see the notes from o365 'message center' and 'recently added' under **health tab** in SP admin center.

In o365 are we running SP 2013 or SP 2016, Is there a way to find the version number from admin center?

If we are running SP 2013. when is the upgrade?
I could not be able to find a tentative date in the roadmap. Please share if there any roadmap available from MSFT.

[Office 365 Roadmap](https://fasttrack.microsoft.com/roadmap?filters=)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint Online was updated to the 16 branch a long time ago. And SharePoint 2016 is as a matter of fact a clone of that 16 branch. So, you could say that SPO runs SP16, which is almost true - SPO and SP on-premises will always be a little bit different.

There's nothing you had to do to update sites from 15 to 16, compared to the 2010 to 2013 upgrades. The SPO Admin center still shows that old UI and eventually that will be updated, once we get the Modern experience there.